# How do I save a FLANN index to disk built from a matrix in C#?

Tags: c#, opencv, matrix, emgucv

I am using this sample code to do image matching (using the OpenCV .NET wrapper called Emgu CV, SURF, and FLANN): http://romovs.github.io/blog/2013/07/05/matching-image-to-a-set-of-images-with-emgu-cv/

My question is, what is the proper way to save this FLANN index to disk and then reopen it for later use?

Also, I'd like to build my matrix directly to disk (as well as the index), so I don't use massive amounts of memory when going through 100,000+ images. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem. It's possible to save the flann index to disk in OpenCV, but EmguCV doesn't wrap all the functions of OpenCV. The `save()` and `load()` functions of Index class are missing in EmguCV.
The solution is to download the EmguCV source code from GIT repository, add the missing functions to it and then recompile the binaries.

You can find the Index wrapper files in `cvextern` project which is available in the EmguCV repository.